# Linking my Humax Foxsat HDR to my wifi (XP) laptop via ethernet

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, ethernet, remote, humax

I want to be able to remote record to my Humax Foxsat HDR and believe that I can do so via a website so if I can get an internet connection to it. Sadly, the SFR box (I'm in France) and the PC are upstairs, TV downstairs. But I have an old XP laptop which I can dedicate to the task while I'm away. So, I've run a cable between the two (UTP CAT5 it says on it). When I look at My Computer and Network Connections, the Humax doesn't show up.

The Humax is asking for - IP address, Subnet Mask, Router Address, DNS, Ethernet ID (already filled in with DC-D3-21-56-C9-18).

I have done ipconfig/all on the laptop and am now overwhelmed with information. Ethernet adaptor Wireless Network Connection has one set of info, Ethernet adaptor LAN has another. Neither has Router Address, and the bits I need don't match. Also, neither IP address matches the one on the "What's my IP" website I'd been told about in former (working) life.

Can anyone help me please?